# Delete [:RELATION] in between two Nodes in Neo4j - No result

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nodes

I'm trying to delete the relation between two nodes using

```
MATCH (:Person{name:"Hugo"})-[r:FOLLOWS]->(:Person{name:"Igor"}) 
DELETE r
```

The relation is completely messed up because of a wrong first attempt query fro relationship. It looks like this:

[image]

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPDATED]

Based on your image, your `MATCH` clause is specifying the wrong direction for the relationship.

To fix this, you have several options.

For example, you could reverse the direction of the relationship:

```
MATCH (:Person{name:"Hugo"})<-[r:FOLLOWS]-(:Person{name:"Igor"})
DELETE r;
```

Or, you could omit the direction:

```
MATCH (:Person{name:"Hugo"})-[r:FOLLOWS]-(:Person{name:"Igor"})
DELETE r;
```

Comment: Or leave off the directional arrow.

Comment: Yh. That's also an option. Just try to define your match as clearly as possible

Comment: I have updated my answer to include omitting the directionality.

Comment: I don't think leaving off the direction is a good idea.  The 'Follows' relationship is not likely to be reciprocal.  If Igor does follow Hugo, leaving off the direction would delete both relationships instead of just the Hugo-follows-Igor relationship that is the problem.

Comment: @user96 I would agree in general for this data model and your use case, but the question was specifically about deleting a single relationship to clean up the db.